# PHP cake subdomains session link problem?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, subdomain

i have problem with php cake session and subdomains. I have setted all successfully right. When i try to go from

```
subdomain1.domain.com
```

to

```
subdomain2.domain.com
```

all works nicely when i put these browser url... problem comes when i try to make this with `<a href=""> tag`, on redirected subdomain i will recieve new session id.

I cant explain to my self how can be this possible, pure php script works fine but in php cake is this bug! thanks for any suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i debug whole php cake session component and lib, i figure out 2 sollutions

1. easier - set in core.php security level to low

   Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
2. advanced - make new config file for sessions, like Ivo said, its in tutorial http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions ,most important thing is set

   ini_restore('session.referer_check');
   because by default php cake check referrer, and if it goes not form same domain it will cause generating new SESSIONID

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related with cake.
By default, PHP will give you a session for the domain.

- subdomain1.domain.com is a domain,
- subdomain2.domain.com is another domain
- domain.com is another different domain
- www.domain.com is another different domain

All thoses examples are 4 distincts domains, with their own session.

If you want to share the session between many (sub)domain, you can try to set the session.cookie_domain variable, like this;

`ini_set("session.cookie_domain","domain.com") ;`

Comment: sorry but like i said "I have setted all successfully right" with this included, and must be ini_set("session.cookie_domain",".domain.com"); for correction, like i said, it works in pure php, but no in phpcake with same configuration... so thanks for reply, but this is not right answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions

Follow the directions to create custom configuration for cake's session saving.